# jQuery select box val undefined in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a bug for now more than 2 hours.
I have a javascript code that generate (from json) a two levels select box for task and subtask.

I just figured out that this code doesn't work on IE9 and maybe other versions, and I was not able to find out why.

I created a JsFiddle to show you my code
http://jsfiddle.net/jkU6Y/18/

The goal is just to find the subtask ID to send via ajax or the task ID if the subtask is not selected.

On IE, I can't get this value and it return undefined.

Comment: no alert in IE9. Seems to work (six alerts) in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned my code and now it's working, so I think that the problem came from the fact that two or more elements may in certain situation have the same ID.

Thanks for your help cbayram and Jan Dvorak, have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

document.write won't register the HTML you are writing out with the DOM in IE. Try to append it to body:

```
$("body").append($(html));
```

Comment: In my real code I'm doing $('#infos-container').append($(html)); 
And it's not working also :(